# Can you over-ride the CSS of a web page displayed in UIWebView?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

Is it possible to load a website with my own local css, ignoring the css used by the site? in UIWebView.

Answer (score 0):

You can use inline styles to override stylesheets: `<div style=" font-size: 10px; ... "> ... </div>`